# C# linq in Dictionary<>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have an object `allStudents = Dictionary<ClassRoom, List<Student>>()`

In Linq how would I get a list of all the students who are male? (student.Gender=="m") from all the Classrooms?

Ian

Comment: There are plenty of homework questions on stackoverflow.  Just tag appropriately.  (In any case, I don't think this one is.)

Comment: I used those objects as they would be universally understood. The real business objects would not be known to the general users. I graduated toooo many years ago to have homework any more ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the following

```
var maleStudents = allStudents
  .SelectMany(x => x.Values)
  .Where(x => x.Gender=="m");
```

The trick to this is the `SelectMany` operation.  It has the effect of flattening a collection of `List<Student>` into a single collection of `Student`.  The resulting list is the same as if you'd lined up each list front to back.

Comment: Yes, the C# compiler translates the query to slightly more complicated code, but I don't think that the difference will matter in any reasonable scenario. It is more important to choose the solution that looks more readable (which is a personal opinion).

Answer (score 19):

You can use nested `from` clause. The first `from` selects all classes together with their students (an item from the dictionary), which is represented as a `KeyValuePair<ClassRoom, List<Student>>`. Then you can select all students from the class using the `Value` property and filter them:

```
var q = from cls in allStudents
        from s in cls.Value
        where s.Gender == "M" select s;
```

Under the cover, the nested `from` clause is translated to the `SelectMany` method call.