# Navigate through dictionary <string, int> c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What is the better way to Navigate through a dictionary  ? I used to use the code below when i had IDictionary:

Assume that I have IDictionary named `freq`

```
IEnumerator enums = freq.GetEnumerator();
while (enums.MoveNext())
{
    string word = (string)enums.Key;
    int val = (int)enums.Value;
    .......... and so on

}
```

but now, I want to do the same thing using dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `foreach` statement iterates automatically through enumerators.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> entry in freq) {
    string word = entry.Key;
    int val = entry.Value;
    .......... and so on

}
```

Comment: so, which one would be faster ? using IEnumerator or foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int>. because the my dictionary contains more than 200000 words.

Comment: `foreach` calls `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` internally. So this should not make any difference. Also the generic variant should be somewhat faster, since the castings are not required any more. Especially `int` has not to boxed and unboxed.

Answer (score 15):

The default enumerator from a `foreach` gives you a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`:

```
foreach (var item in dictionary)
// foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in dictionary)
{
    var key = item.Key;
    var value = item.Value;
}
```

This simply compiles into code that works directly with the enumerator as in your old code.

Or you can enumerate the `.Keys` or `.Values` directly (but you only get a key or a value in that case):

```
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)

foreach (var val in dictionary.Values)
```

And or course linq works against dictionaries:

[C# linq in Dictionary<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549563/c-sharp-linq-in-dictionary)

Comment: for using Var, does this will effect on the data type of the the key and the value in term of string , int respectively? I' not friendly with using var, that why I ask

Comment: @JoneMamni: No - `var` just gives the variable a type inferred from the *compile-time* type of the assigned value. There's no impact at execution time.

Comment: @JoneMamni No, in this case `var` is inferred from the type of the key and value, in your case with a generic dictionary this would be string and int.

Answer (score 8):

Well you *could* do the same thing with `Dictionary`, but it would be cleaner to use `foreach` in *both* cases:

```
foreach (var entry in dictionary)
{
    string key = entry.Key;
    int value = entry.Value;
    // Use them...
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
using (var iterator = dictionary.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        var entry = iterator.Current;
        string key = entry.Key;
        int value = entry.Value;
        // Use them...
    }
}
```

It's *very* rarely useful to explicitly call `GetEnumerator` and iterate yourself. It's appropriate in a handful of cases, such as when you want to treat the first value differently, but if you're going to treat *all* entries the same way, use `foreach`.

(Note that it really is equivalent to using `var` here, but *not* equivalent to declaring an `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` - it will actually use the nested [`Dictionary.Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3z2hhax.aspx) struct. That's a detail you *usually* don't need to worry about.)